# Installing mysqlclient for python

Tags: python, mysql

I have installed mysql-server (5.7.21) locally. Then I tried to install mysqlclient, but get an error `"mysql_config: not found"`. I found that I should install `libmysqlclient-dev`. I ran `sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev`and get a new error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libmysqlclient-dev : Depends: libmysqlclient20 (= 5.7.21-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) but 5.7.21-1ubuntu16.04 is to be installed
```

How can I solve this dependencies conflict?

Comment: Try to install version `5.7.21-1ubuntu16.04` instead of `5.7.21-0ubuntu0.16.04.1` as the error states.

Comment: When `unmet dependencies` happen, try running `sudo apt -f install`. That will try to fix dependencies issue.